# Salesforce site lists no visualforce pages

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I'm trying to add a new visualforce page to a salesforce site, but the site admin lists no visualforce pages and does not have the 'edit' button that I'd usually use to edit the pages associated with a site.  I've attached a screenshot of this:

[image: SalesForce site admin]

I know that this site definitely has visualforce pages associated with it, so I'm not sure why it's listing no pages.  Is there some sort of setting that could cause the admin to behave in  this way?  Maybe the site is locked or something?

To make things a little stranger, I have a sandbox for this environment in which the site appears as expected.

Comment: do you have multiple sites by any chance and are looking at the wrong one. Just wondering : )..it's a weird one.

Comment: @PepeFloyd Nope, definitely the right site.

Comment: What happens if you force yourself into the "Edit" page? URL looks like `https://eu1.salesforce.com/_ui/system/user/ProfileApexPagePermissionEdit/e?profile_id={id}` (get ProfileId from queries or from clicking the "Public Access Settings" button and looking at the URL). Is the site active? Does it have at least 1 "custom url" generated?

Comment: @eyescream I get a an "Insufficient priveleges" error when I go to that page manually, which I suppose may be the issue.  The site is active, and it has a couple of custom URLs

Comment: Did anybody demote you? Are you still a system administrator?

Comment: @eyescream By the looks of things, that's right.  Should have really checked in the first place.  If you put that as an answer I'll mark you correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has anybody demoted you? Are you (still) a System Administrator? If buttons don't show up and when you hack the url you get "Insufficient Priviledges"...

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=sites_creating_and_editing_sites.htm mentions the right to "Customize Application".

https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=sites_configuring_sites.htm adds "Manage Users".

I thought more than that is needed to assign VF pages to Profiles but well, it's a start ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found out that "Manage Users" is required along with "Customize Application"...this is unfortunate since I feel like it gives too much access.